# Why doesn't this code skip the first line of the file?

Tags: python, file

```
fp = open("Fruits.csv", 'r')
exampleDictionary = {}
line = fp.readline()
while line is not '':
    # the line can have some trailing characters, like 'newline'
    line = line.rstrip()
    items, types, numberItems, color  = line.split(',')

    # split it into parts, to get the total price
    exampleDictionary[items] = types
    # add this part's price to the total price of the car
    # remember: everything we get from the split() is a string.
    #price_of_car += int(total_price_of_part)
    
    print(items, types, numberItems, color)
    # read in a new line
    line = fp.readline()
print(exampleDictionary)
fp.close()
```

This outputs something like this:

```
Items Type Number of items Color
Apples Fruit 3 Red
Oranges Fruit 5 Orange
Mangos Fruit 4 Yellow
Legos Toys 6 Red
{'Items': 'Type', 'Apples': 'Fruit', 'Oranges': 'Fruit', 'Mangos': 'Fruit', 'Legos': 'Toys'}
```

When I don't include line = fp.readline() before the while loop it skips the first column. I was wondering if someone could explain why this happening.

The file looks like this:

```
  Items Type  Number of items  Color
  Apples Fruit 3 Red
  Oranges Fruit 5 Orange
  Mangos Fruit 4 Yellow
  Legos Toys 6 Red'
```

Comment: The `line` that was read ahead of the loop is the line that is being processed by the first iteration of the loop.  The `line` read at the very end of the loop is used on all subsequent iterations.  If you want to skip that header line, you need another `fp.readline()` at the top.

Comment: And `'Items Type Number of items Color' is not ''` is `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, it's not the optimal solution but it works like this

```
fp = open("Fruits.csv", 'r')
exampleDictionary = {}
line = fp.readline()
while line is not '':
    #Read line at first to skip the first line
    line = fp.readline()
    #check if line is ''
    if(line == ''):
        break
    # the line can have some trailing characters, like 'newline'
    line = line.rstrip()
    items, types, numberItems, color = line.split(",")

    # split it into parts, to get the total price
    exampleDictionary[items] = types
    # add this part's price to the total price of the car
    # remember: everything we get from the split() is a string.
    # price_of_car += int(total_price_of_part)
    print(items, types, numberItems, color)
print(exampleDictionary)
fp.close()
```

Or you can read the line two times at first and conserve your code.